# Is asking for recommendations about plugins on topic?

Tags: discussion

Can a question such as below be on topic ?
If it is off topic, why is it off topic ?
And how should I improve it to make it on topic ?

> I'm curious about finding plugins used by developers who write code
>   using vim. I'm interested in c++ related plugins only, can I get a
>   list of suggestions ?

Comment: *"how should I improve it to make it on topic?"* -> Your example question is not just asking for plugins, it's also very broad & unspecific; is something like surround.vim "C++ related"? And what about Syntastic? Or indentline? A good question should state a specific problem you're having. You can [browse the filetype-c++ tag](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filetype-c%2b%2b) for some inspiration.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker couldn't find the original question when I searched, thanks for the suggestion.